# css drop down menu. Located at left sidebar. Incorrect location (top) for the first submenu box

Tags: html, css

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/yysdged6/19/

Tutorial here http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

HTML like this

```
<nav>
<ul>

<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Option One</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Option One 1</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Option One 1 longer</a> </li>
    </ul>
</li>

</ul>
</nav>
```

If I move cursor over `Option One` I want the submenu to appear in the same line as `Option One`

Like here

```
Home
Option One   Option One 1
             Option One 1 longer
```

But I get this

```
Home         Option One 1
Option One   Option One 1 longer
```

Here is the css

```
nav ul ul { display: none; }

nav ul li:hover > ul { display: block; }

nav ul {
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
}

nav ul:after { content: ""; clear: both; display: block; }

nav ul li a { 
display: block;  
}

nav ul ul { 
/* */ position: absolute; left: 100%; top: 0;
/* position: relative; */
/* position: absolute; left: 100%; top: 100%; */
background: grey;
}

nav ul ul li {
float: none;
position: relative;
width: 160px;
}

nav ul ul ul { position: absolute; left: 100%; top: 0; }
```

As I understand it is because in `nav ul ul` `position: absolute; left: 100%; top: 0;` Instead of `top: 0;` need something other. But I do not understand what?

For comparison location for deeper level submenus is correct. Incorrect location is only for 1st level submenu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to remove the relative position from the `ul` element and add it to the `li` 
http://jsfiddle.net/yysdged6/20/